# Workload identity to connect a GKE cluster to a different GCP project

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, workload-identity

Is it possible to use workload identity to access from a GKE pod to a GCP service of another project? A project that is different from the one in which the GKE cluster is created.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the main idea behind this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. If the service account bind with your K8S service account is autorize to access to resources in other projects, there is no issue. It's the same thing with your user account or other service accounts: Grant the account the access to the ressources and that's enough!